# Get Part of filename batch

Tags: batch-file, pattern-matching

I have a directory with following files:

```
PPP1234MM.xml
PPP4532MM.xml
PPP9843MM.xml
```

I need to extract the numeric parts of the filenames using batch command. Please help!

Comment: Always in 3char+4digits+2char format?

Comment: it could be more than 4 digits appearing and ending with 2 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l /a-d /b *.xml') do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%n in ("%%~nf") do (
        echo File: %%~nxf = Number %%n
    )
)
```

Use the non numeric characters as delimiters in a `for` command to remove them of the name. The list of files is retrieved in lowercase to limit the number of delimiters in list.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is the same of your question (3 characters, 4-digit, 2 characters), use the code below, if you have other standards to help inform you better.

```
@echo off
@title Get Part of filename batch
@color 0a

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%A in ( "*.xml" ) do (

  REM Set Filename
  set "FileFull=%%~nxA"

  REM Set Number, offset equal 3 (skip 3 first characteres), length equal 4 (four characteres)
  set "FileNumber=!FileFull:~3,4!"

  echo !FileNumber!

)

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "ppp*.xml" '
 ) DO (
 SET "number="
 SET "name=%%a"
 CALL :process "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
:notnum
IF DEFINED number GOTO show
:num
SET "name=%name:~1%"
:process
IF NOT DEFINED name GOTO show
if "%name:~0,1%" lss "0" GOTO notnum
if "%name:~0,1%" gtr "9" GOTO notnum
SET "number=%number%%name:~0,1%"
GOTO num

:show
ECHO file %1 --^> %number%
GOTO :eof
```

This should extract and show the numeric part. You may wish to change the filematch mask. I simply used `ppp*.xml` for my testing